# FullCalendar End Date Off By One

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

when I create an event, the end date of that event is always 1 after. I know there's a lot of people with this problem and their are many solutions floating around involving the use of the `allDay = false` parameter. But the difference between my problem and theirs is that my calendar allows the user to input not only the date but also the time.

So I did some string manipulation like so:

```
                var end_date = end.format("DD");
                end_date  = end_date - 1;
                console.log("End date:" + end_date);
                if(end_date == 0){
                    end = start;
                }
                else{
                    if (end_date < 10){
                        end = end.format("YYYY-MM")+"-0"+end_date;
                    }
                    else{
                        end = end.format("YYYY-MM")+"-"+end_date;
                    }
                }
```

But this only works if the event is within the span of one day. If I create an event of three days long it will only show for two days. For example:

[image]
As you can see from the modal form, it should be 3 days long not 2. I tried and researched everywhere but could not find a solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Only Month is zero based in a javascript `Date`, date and year are not. Try removing `end_date  = end_date - 1;`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: No but I need the end_date - 1 because the end date is 1 more than what I set it to be.