# FullCalendar - start/end date is off by one day

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm using fullCalendar and it use work fine except recently and maybe its updated to new version which I don't know.
so the issue I'm having is start/end date is off.
so I fixed the start date off by 1 day by adding timeZone: 'UTC'

and end date still have one day short and I debug and it looks like its getting the correct data from the server but when it renders its getting one day short.
for an example:

my end date ends March 8 but in the calendar showing March 7

I looked at this existing solution but could not find the answer:
[FullCalendar End Date Off By One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42545657/fullcalendar-end-date-off-by-one)
[Fullcalendar show "end date" one day off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27960971/fullcalendar-show-end-date-one-day-off)

when I debug this is the data I'm getting which is correct:

```
{
    "id": "SDFDS23",
    "editable": true,
    "startEditable": true,
    "durationEditable": true,
    "start": "2024-03-04T00:00:00.000Z",
    "end": "2024-03-08T00:00:00.000Z",
    "allDay": true,
    "title": "test",
     
}
```

here is my code:

```
this.calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(ele, {
        plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list' ],
        defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
        timeZone: 'UTC',
        navLinks: true,  
        editable: true,
        droppable: true,  
        selectable: this.selectable,
        selectMirror: true,
        eventLimit: true,  
        eventDurationEditable: true,
        eventStartEditable: true,
        eventResizableFromStart: true,
        slotDuration: "00:30:00",
        snapDuration: "00:30:00",
        defaultTimedEventDuration: "01:00:00" ,
        footerToolbar: true,
        nowIndicator: true,
        now: new Date(),
        eventTimeFormat: {
          hour: '2-digit',
          minute: '2-digit',
          meridiem: true
        },
```

read all the documentation and search the stackoverflow but could not find any answer

Comment: `2024-03-08T00:00:00.000Z` is midnight at the beginning of 3/8. I suspect that this is why the last day you see is 3/7...

Comment: As per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing, end dates in fullCalendar are **exclusive**. This has been the case since version 1 - nothing has changed in that respect. This gets asked about [repeatedly](https://www.google.com/search?q=fullcalendar+end+date+one+less+site:stackoverflow.com) - it seems that nobody reads the documentation properly.

Comment: @NirAlfasi    is there any other setting do I need to set in order not to have midnight?

Comment: If you want your event to show as covering the whole of the 8th March, then it needs to end at the _end_ of that day, not the start of that day. Since end dates are _exclusive_ (as I mentioned above), then you would need to set the end date as `2024-03-09T00:00:00.000Z` instead

Comment: @ADyson so there are no other way other than adding +1 to the end date ?

Comment: is that official doc that suggest to add +1 day in order to show the correct date ?

Comment: It doesn't suggest it no, it just explains how it interprets the dates you provide to it. The logical conclusion from that is the suggestion I have given, to add 1 day to your date. Or if you prefer you could give `2024-03-08T23:59:59.000Z` as the end date. Personally I think that's a bit messy, but it's up to you. All you need to do is understand how the date system in fullcalendar works (as per the documentation), and then you can act according to your own preference based on that knowledge

Comment: thanks, so my dates are coming from the database the end date comes in the this format `2024-03-08T00:00:00.000Z`

Comment: in my database the `start date is: 2024-03-04 and end date is 2024-03-08`

Comment: Ok. Well it's not hard to add a day to a date, just when you share it with the calendar.

Comment: it's not about adding a day to a date but more of a question understanding why this is behaving the way its so I fix the core instead of adding one day to it, so I'm not sure where its adding all the time to it, I'm still not understanding. and in my database I have 2024-04-08 but somehow its add this time `T00:00:00.000Z`

Comment: Well, all dates have times, even if you don't explicitly state it. Most computer systems would understand that if you provide a date without a time then, in a time-aware context (such as fullcalendar), it's a shorthand for midnight on that date. It's not clear, logically, what else it could be expected to represent? Fullcalendar, and any calendar system (google calendar behaves the same way, for example), need to understand specifically where the event starts and ends. If you only give it a date without a time, then inevitably it has to assume something about the time of day.

Comment: @Basil think of it as if you're doing `"ABC".substring(0,2)` which resolves to the string 'AB' even though "ABC"[2] === 'C'. When you create a calendar with a start and end date, the end date itself is not included in the calendar but used as "not included top limit". So it's not that "you just have to add 1" but rather "you just have to understand how calendar works" in order to specify the correct end date :)

Comment: so even if I have specific the date with time while creating the records still shows me 12:00 so for an example startDate `March 10 at 08:00 am to 11:00 am` and endDate `March 12 at 08:00 am to 11:00 am` and still shows the date range from `March 10 to March 11`

Comment: `startDate March 10 at 08:00 am to 11:00 am` makes no sense. That's a start time _and_ and end time. You can't have two times in a start time! Please provide your actual JSON event data for this example instead, then we can see what you're _actually_ passing to the calendar - I'm guessing maybe you've just mangled the description.

Comment: my mistake that was typo I meant to say startDate March 10 at 08:00 am and endDate March 12 at 11:am, let me generate the json and paste here.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense. Make sure you haven't set `allDay: true` otherwise it will ignore the times you've provided. Again this is mentioned in the documentation at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing : _"If your event is explicitly allDay, hour, minutes, seconds and milliseconds will be ignored"_